# pie chart matplotlib 'tuple' object is not callable error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels='bye_runs','legbye_runs','noball_runs','penalty_runs','batsman_runs','extra_runs'  
size=[680,3056,612,10,166009,9519]
plt.pie(size,labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

This is my code for pie chart but it shows typeerror at line 4 as

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, this works for me.

Comment: When asking about an error, you need to make the problem reproducible. Hence include the full error traceback, not just its last line.